# How to fix FirebaseNotifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle, android-push-notification

I have implemented Fire base notifications properly some devices not receiving notifications vivo,infocus while running background  how to resolve that issue

```
 public void getNotification(String icon,String title,String body){
      remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification_big);
      remoteView  = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification_small);
      //Bitmap bitmap = SetImage(remote.getIcon()) ;
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      if(icon!=null && !icon.isEmpty()){
        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image_pic,bitmap);
      }else{

      }
      if(title != null && !title.isEmpty()){
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,title);
      }
      if(body != null && !body.isEmpty()){
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,body);
      }
      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
              .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
              .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
              .setContentTitle("Notification")
              .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
              .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
              .setAutoCancel(true)
              .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
              .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      {
          notificationBuilder1.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
      } else
      {
          notificationBuilder1.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

      }
      notificationManager.notify(100, notificationBuilder1.build());

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add channel for this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                NotificationChannel(
                    "YOUR_ID",
                    "YOUR_NAME",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                )
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notification not received!**

To make firebase to call your onMessageReceived() in the following cases

**1) App in foreground
2) App in background
3) App has been killed**

you must not put JSON key 'notification' in your request/InApp to firebase API but instead use 'data'.

**You can follow the doc.**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications